# Non-ECR category for an Indian Passport, without birth certificate, class 10 cert. and No PAN

Tags: indian-citizens, passports, india

I am planning to apply for a new passport for my mother-in-law, she is over 50 years and falls under the non-ECR category.

She doesn't have a birth certificate, 10th marks card or a PAN card. She only has a voter ID and an Aadhar card.

Are those documents accepted with the passport application?

Answer (score 4):

All Indian residents having the age of 50 years or more fall in the Non-ECR category ([Source](https://www.mea.gov.in/emigration-abroad-for-emp.htm)). As your mother-in-law is aged over 50, she will not be given an ECR stamp in her passport.

The [revised list of documents](https://portal2.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/pdf/PressRelease_PassportRule.pdf) which can be used as proof of date of birth mentions the following:

> - Birth  Certificate  (BC)  issued  by  the  Registrar of  Births  &  Deaths  or  the Municipal Corporation or any other prescribed
>     authority whosoever has been empowered under the Registration of Birth
>     & Deaths Act, 1969 to register the birth of a child born in India
> - Transfer/School leaving/Matriculation Certificate issued by the school last attended/recognized educational board containing the DOB
>     of the applicant
> - PAN Card issued by the Income Tax Department with the DOB of applicant
> - **Aadhaar Card/E-Aadhaar having the DOB of applicant**
> - Copy of the extract of the service record of the applicant (only in respect of Government  servants)  or  the  Pay  Pension  Order  (in 
>     respect  of  retired Government  Servants),  duly  attested/certified 
>     by  the  officer/in-charge  of  the Administration of the concerned
>     Ministry/Department of the applicant, having his DOB
> - Driving  license  issued  by  the  Transport  Department  of  concerned  State Government, having the DOB of applicant
> - **Election Photo Identity Card (EPIC) issued by the Election Commission of India having the DOB of applicant**

If her Aadhar card and voter card have her full DOB mentioned, then those can be used.

NOTE: The [Document advisor](https://portal2.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/onlineHtml/NonEcrDocuments.html) does not list all documents acceptable for age related Non-ECR category but I think the latest MEA advisory is the one applicable here.

Comment: I applied for my mother with only Aadhar and election ID. I can vouch that it works. Just to note - if she is a government employee, she need to submit an NOC from her office.